# Crystal report display line as expected in the image

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qasTG.png)

I have taken data from access and data is displayed in the crystal report. I have inserted a line in the detail section but I need to make the line thicker at the end of the transaction as in the image shown. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where the report is grouped on Order ID.
I inserted a line at the bottom of the detail section,
right-clicked the line, selected 'Format Line...' and entered the following expression for the line-width:

```
If onlastrecord then crThreePointLine else 
if Next({Orders_Detail.Order ID}) <> {Orders_Detail.Order ID} then crThreePointLine 
else crOnePointLine
```

[image: Dynamic Expression for Line Width]

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have inserted the line at the bottom of the detail section but I don't see an option to enter a formula in line width.  I am using crystal report 9.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, split the detail section into 'Detail a' and 'Detail b' sections.
And control the visibility (using an expression for the Suppress attribute of each section) so that only one version is visible using similar logic.